Woman needs something opened, man crushes it to bits
OK, this will sound pretty vague but I can't remember that much about the actors, all I remember is the scene that goes something like this. I think it's some comedy movie but anyway the scene is a man and woman are in either a bar or at a house party and from what I remember she picks up a walnut or something that needs to be opened. The man offers to open it for her and in the process crushes it to bits and hands it back to her all in pieces. This is all I remember it has been in my head for a while and would love to know what film it is from because it was really funny.
It was definitely in English, possibly an American movie. Not to sure if it was a TV show, I more remember it as a film but I could be wrong. Sorry for not having more information!
